# Determining transfer speed over websocket

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, websocket

I've done my obligatory Googling and I can't seem to find a suitable answer to this...

Is there a way to determine the upload and download rate/speed over a web socket connection using JavaScript? For instance, if I want to pull canvas data from a very large canvas (or use any other large chunk of data) and pass it to the server over a web socket connection in a single message, is there a way to determine how long it takes that message to actually send, though not necessarily have been received by the server?

Maybe breaking the data into smaller pieces and sending over a series of messages would work also, but still, I don't know of a way to determine when the message was actually sent. I'm aware that AJAX gives upload and download progress, but I'd prefer to use web sockets if possible.

Comment: Websocket is a thin protocol on top of TCP so this will depend on your network performance.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'm asking if there's a way to programmatically determine when a message is starting to send and when it's finished sending, and the same for receiving.